# Would a 404 be acceptable for a DELETE method being called on a non-existent URL?

Tags: rest, http, web, http-status-codes, http-delete

I am pretty new to the RESTful world, and at the moment I'm debating whether when calling a delete method on a URL that doesn't exist, whether a `404 Resource Not Found` should be returned. At the moment, the code returns a `200 OK` code, but this doesn't inform a user that what they wanted to do wasn't possible.

I have looked online and on here, and a lot of people have divided opinions on the matter, with HTTP having no standards on return codes.

(I'm thinking in a scenario where someone wants to delete something but through something like a typo, deletes an invalid resource but through there being no error code returned, isn't informed that the delete was unsuccessful, and doesn't realise the mistake.)

Answer (score 0):

I would return the 404 and allow the front-end developer to decide how to handle the situation. As a front-end developer if my user attempted to delete a resource that did not exist, I would like to handle that situation. It could be that the resource was deleted by another user between the time that I found the resource and the present. On the other hand it could be that there was a typo like you said.

But regardless, I would like to know if the user is attempting to delete a resource that no longer exists so that I may handle the situation appropriately.

But this situation depends on the type of application you are constructing. For example, you may want to return a 410 in the case that another user deleted the resource in the last 5 minutes, then return a 404 for all non-existent URLs. But once again, I would only expect a 200 to be returned if something was actually deleted.

SharePoint REST follows this pattern.